# Video is auto resizing me

Tags: javascript, css, html5-video, getusermedia

I'm trying to make a cam capture component, I want that it's resized to fit the 100% of the div that contains it.
This is how I have the video.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {

      // Indicates the possible video quality.
      width: { min: 640, ideal: 1024, max: 1920 },
      height: { min: 480, ideal: 720, max: 1080 }
    }})
    .then(stream => {
     // Code over here
        }));
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
     // Error over here
      }));
    });
}
```

In my CSS I have this.

```
#video {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%!important;
  height: auto!important;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); //avoid mirror effect
  transform: scaleX(-1);

}
```

The "error" appears when I want that the quality of the video is another one bigger than 640x480, then the video> resize automatically and does not work properly, because I do crops on image then I analyze it and other things that no matters right now.

Is it possible to make an improvement of quality without resizing video?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the video input's size with `getUserMedia`, you cannot change its actual size, only the `<video>` element's size - the input's (camera input) dimensions do not change, which can lead to cropping and pixeling your video display.

I assume you're using the `video.srcObject = stream;` command to set the input (stream) to the `<video>` element.

If you want to resize the actual input's dimension, you will need to reattach the `srcObject` to a **new** stream object after calling `getUserMedia` again, with the new dimensions.

For example:

```
var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
        mandatory: {
            minWidth: CANVAS_WIDTH,
            minHeight: CANVAS_HEIGHT,
            maxWidth: CANVAS_WIDTH,
            maxHeight: CANVAS_HEIGHT
        }
    }
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then( ... )
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to change the dimensions of the video, I am looking for improving the quality without change the dimension, I mean, capture a video on 1920x1080px (Talking about quality, thinking about full hd) but the size video tag should be 640x480